# Why my userNotificationCenter didReceive not run when fired

Tags: notifications, background, swift4

I use UserNotifications make a simple notification for test, I wrote the code in AppDelegate as below, when the notification fired in background, it will shows the message on the screen, but it doesn't run the code both print(...) and a.get()) :

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    print("run in didReceive")

    let a = ViewController()
    a.get()

}


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {


    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert,.sound,.badge, .carPlay], completionHandler: { (granted, error) in
        if granted {
            print("granted")
        }else{
            print("not granted")
        }
    })

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

    return true
}
```

I just only want to run a "viewcontroller" function when the app when in background...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is this line:

```
let a = ViewController()
```

You are creating a "loose" view controller and then throwing it away. What you probably want is a reference to some *existing* view controller that is *already* in the interface.

A broader problem might be a false assumption about what `userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:)` is for. It is not called to indicate that a notification alert appeared (i.e. the notification fired). It is called to indicate that the *user interacted* with the notification, such as tapping or (if so configured) dismissing the alert. A banner alert that just appears and goes away again, with no user interaction, will not cause `userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:)` to be called.

Comment: But, why even the "print(....)" doesn't run? And I tried both ViewController().get() and ViewController.get() are not right.....weird

Comment: By default you don't get any event if the notification just appears. The user has to tap on it in order for something to happen.

Comment: Added that to my answer.

Comment: Oh,  you explain this really clear, I know it now, I was wrong. But, final, how I do run function when notification is fired in background ?